# Rails testing best practices when one ActiveRecord model requires another

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have two models, one of which requires the existence of the other to validate:

```
class Mother < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end

class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mother
  validates_presence_of :mother
end
```

When I'm writing tests for model Kid, the first thing I want to test is that a Kid can't be saved without having a Mother that is present (ie persisted in the database). However, to do that, I'd need to have my tests first create an Mother.

What is the best way to handle this situation? Should I:

- Seed the test database with instances of Mother before I test?
- Rely on the unit tests for Mother to create instances of Mother, before Kid gets tested? In which case, I'd have to specify the order of tests, which isn't recommended, correct?
- Some other option?

Comment: Neither, you should do whatever your testing framework provides. Fixtures or factories. You should **not** write tests that depend on other tests, in fact it should be impossible for this to happen because your database should be emptied between tests.

Comment: @meagar I think this should be the accepted answer - either fixtures or factories. Could you reply again as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a Mother and a Kid without a mother : 
`mother = Mother.new`
Puis 
`kid = Kid.new`

You can first write a spec that raises an error when you try to persist a Kid like so: 
`expect { kid.save! }.to raise_error`

Then, set the mother `kid.mother = mothe` . 
And expect to persist the kid with no error this time.